# Append string to json using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

How can i append a string to existing json or re-write to new json.

Here is my existing json

```
[
      {
        "Robin": "id1"
      },
      {
        "John": "id2"
      },
      {
        "Jane": "id3"
      }
    ]
```

The expected json is

```
{
"Objects":
[
      {
        "Robin": "id1"
      },
      {
        "John": "id2"
      },
      {
        "Jane": "id3"
      }
    ]
}
```

i looked at some existing posts w.r.t jq, however they are not helping as string intended to append has double quotes in it. can some one help me?

Comment: Have you tried `jq '{objects: .}' oldfile.json > newfile.json`? And have a look at [Object Construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction%3A%7B%7D) `{}` and the [Identity filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Identity%3A.) `.`.

Comment: Which string do you want to add? Do you want to wrap your array in an object that has a single property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go from your given input to the given output, construct a new object with the [`{}` filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D) defining a single property which has the full input array (via [identity `.`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Identity:.) filter) as value:

```
{ Objects: . }
```

If the key's name itself is variable, you can define a variable to be used by jq:

```
jq --arg key Objects '{ $key: . }' input.json > output.json
```